# Entity Framework Dynamic Mapping

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, silverlight-4.0, entity, poco

I have a EntityAttributeValue database that I have no control over. To get the data I use a stored proc as follows.

```
public class PhotoDataContext : DbContext, IPhotoDataContext
    {
public IEnumerable<PhotoRegistration> GetPhotoRegistration()
        {
            return this.Database.SqlQuery<PhotoRegistration>("SP_Photo") ;
        }
}
```

This works fine for when the POCO maps perfectly. Now I have a stored procedure that can return dynamic fields. All fields are of string type.

I am using EF 4.1 Code First and am passing the POCO's to Silverlight via WCF.
Any ideas how to stop the auto mapping of EF and to pivot the data back into a name value pair that WCF will be happy to serialize.

Thanks
J

Answer (score 0):

Use ADO.NET = `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` (or equivalent if you don't use SQL Server). Entity framework doesn't like dynamic result sets.